# unzip извлекает с поддиректориями

Tags: ubuntu

При попытке извлечь файл zip  в ubuntu через **unzip**, извлекается отдельно каждый файл с указанием поддиректории (куча файлов):

```
sudo unzip arch.zip -d /var/www/test

ls /var/www/gs/

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\rent
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\security
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\site
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\smev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\source
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\statement
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\stock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\vehicle
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 protected\views\xmlparsing
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 сент. 27 18:01 public
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 public\css
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 public\css\images
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 public\fonts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 public\img
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 дек.  28  2015 public\img\_temp
```

а надо, чтобы были папки public protected итд, как это сделать? В архиве структура нормальная.

Comment: а что выводит _unzip -l arch.zip_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в архиве с *нормальной структурой* слеши не те.
В windows разделитель каталогов \, в unix - /.

Выгребайте из архива с -j (без каталогов) и раскидывайте ручками.

Comment: зачем ручками, если есть готовые скрипты, которые это фиксят? http://serverfault.com/questions/359893/convert-back-slash-file-names-into-directories